# Printing using VBA code not the same as using UI

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a problem with my Excel file.  I am copying graphs from other files and pasting them as sheets so they are now "Chart Sheets".  All of this works fine but the issue comes when printing.  I have a page setup macro that sets the margins and footer and IF I print it using the print button it comes out fine.  The graph is nicely centered and white space is equal all around, it is printing the same as it appears in Print Preview.  The problem is when I print from VBA using either of the following codes:

```
Sheets("83IO").Activate
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

or

```
Sheets("83IO").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

These printouts have the charts off to the side and double the whitespace on the bottom and right.  Changing the margins does not seem to alter these printout and I'm at a loss what to do with this.

I've tried setting `IgnorePrintAreas` to true since these pages are nothing but graphs and the result is the same.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I'm getting run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error on that line

Comment: What happens when you do the page setup in the same procedure before issuing a `.Printout`

Comment: I've added a Call to the code that does all the formatting right in the print macro and it's the same outcome.  I have thought of a solution but I'm not sure how to work it.  I would like to pick these sheets and insert a blank sheet between each and generate the print preview.

Comment: How would inserting a blank sheet help?

Comment: I can not control duplex printing so inserting blank pages would fix the duplex issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`.PageSetup.PrintArea`**:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("83IO")

    .PageSetup.PrintArea = .Shapes(1).TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & _
                           .Shapes(1).BottomRightCell.Address

    With .PageSetup
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = True
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = 100
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
    End With
    .PrintPreview
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: That doesn't work and I believe it's because my charts are sheets, they are not selectable objects.

Comment: Using that gives me "The index into the specified collection is out of bounds."